# Javascript total function not working

Tags: javascript

I have a "getPrice" function which works fine and calculates the prices of multiple events.

Within that function lies my loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

    // STORE a reference to aInputElements[ counter ]
    var currentElement = inputs[i];

    // IF currentElement is a checkbox AND currentElement is checked
    if (currentElement.type == "checkbox" && currentElement.checked) {

        eventTotal = eventTotal + +currentElement.title;

    }

}

// Assign total to input with "£" infront
totalbox.value = "£" + parseFloat(eventTotal).toFixed(2);
```

However, when i try to calculate the price and delivery together, only the first event selected on the list is added to the total:

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

    // STORE a reference to aInputElements[ counter ]
    var currentElement = inputs[i];

    // IF currentElement is a checkbox AND currentElement is checked
    if (currentElement.type == "checkbox" && currentElement.checked) {

        eventTotal = eventTotal + currentElement.title;

    }

    // IF currentElement is radio AND currentElement is checked
    if (currentElement.type == "radio" && currentElement.checked) {

        deliveryTotal = deliveryTotal + currentElement.title;

    }

}

// Assign total to input with "£" infront - Parse into a number (as a float) - to 2 decimal places
totalbox.value = "£" + (parseFloat(eventTotal) + parseFloat(deliveryTotal)).toFixed(2);
```

Could somebody kindly advise as to what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: Didn't you just post this a few minutes ago?

Comment: Yes, however the preview question was deleted as i decided to rewrite it to try and make it more clear.

Comment: Shouldn't you parse the floats when they're being added together, rather than afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Are the inputs.length really what you think it would be? 
Maybe you named the checkboxes wrongly?

Add `alert('currentElement is [' + currentElement + ']');` right after your `var currentElement = inputs[i];` and see.